# Expo application IPA not working on my iphone

Tags: ios, react-native, build, itunes, expo

I created an application in React Native with Expo and I want to generate APK and IPA files.

So I used:

```
exp build:android
exp build:ios
```

I had no problem with the APK file and it works very well on my Android.
Unfortunately, I have a little more problems with iOS. Indeed, I want my IPA file to be accessible through a URL. For that I made an app.plist file which is structured like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
   <key>items</key>
    <array>
     <dict>
       <key>assets</key>
       <array>
         <dict>
           <key>kind</key>
           <string>software-package</string>
           <key>url</key>
           <string>https://url/file.ipa</string>
         </dict>
       </array>
       <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
          <key>bundle-identifier</key>                                    
            <string>BUNDLE_ID</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>4.0</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>subtitle</key>
            <string>41A472</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>APP_NAME</string>
           </dict>
         </dict>
       </array>
    </dict>
   </plist>
```

But when I try to install the application through the url (***itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://url/app.plist***), the installation stucks and tells me to try again later. I also tried to install the application with iTunes and I have the same problem. I think the problem is that Expo build the app for the AppStore and I wanted to know if there was not a solution for my method to work...

I specify that I work on WIndows and Linux, but do not hesitate if you have a solution on MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same problem before. Basically, there's only one official way to test a standalone app on your iOS device, and that's via TestFlight (I know, it's not great). You can refer to [this page](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html) for more details. I found several online services for installing IPAs without AppStore, but they all looked shady to me, so I didn't risk using them.

Also, you probably already know it, but you don't need to build an IPA to test your app on a real device. You can do it with the Expo app on your smartphone and [Expo CLI tools](https://expo.io/tools#cli) on your computer by running `exp start` in the root of your app project.